# In ASP.net Core my returnToAction("index", "Login") is going to Login/Login on production

Tags: asp.net, view

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(User user)
{
    try
    {    
         user.Password = EncryptDecrypt.EncryptString(user?.Password);
         var result = await ecleDbService.GetUser(user, baseUrl);
         if (result != null && result.LoginName != null)
         {  
              HttpContext.Session.SetString("LoginUser", user.LoginName);
              TempData["LoginUser"] = HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoginUser");
              return RedirectToAction("ClientList", "Client");
         }
         else
         {   // need to not redirect but show login failed
             TempData["LoginError"] = "Login for user: " + user.LoginName + " failed.";
             TempData["EmailMessage"] = "For support email: myemail@myemail.com";
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
         }

         //return View("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;
        return View();
    }
}
```

I get this error on production wherre it tries to load the folderName.cshtml rather than index.cshtml
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Login/Login.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

The issue was i was throwing a catch which then loaded View(), rather than the redirectToAction() I was expecting